# react native - `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition` returns "No location provider available"

Tags: geolocation, react-native

I'm trying to use this library: `@react-native-community/geolocation`

```
const requestLocationPermission = async (success, failure) => {
try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    )

    if( granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED ) {
        console.log("You can use the location")

        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            ({ coords }) => {
                console.log("coords: ", coords)
            },
            (errObject) => {
                console.log("message: ", errObject) // it gets thrown here
            }
        )
    } else {
        console.log("You cannot use the location")
    }
  } catch (err) {

  }
}
```

It prompts user to either allow or deny the app access to their location. After allowing I get this:

```
{"PERMISSION_DENIED": 1, "POSITION_UNAVAILABLE": 2, "TIMEOUT": 3, "code": 2, "message": "No location provider available."}
```

In `AndroidMenufest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: I am facing same issue! Any updates you made later to fix this ? @Sumit

Answer (score 0):

Nothing need more just do like this useState(0) for both lat and lang don't provide any string write this Geolocation.getCurrentPosition((data)=>(console.log(data)
//here you can set the states
))

Answer (score 0):

Just turn on the device location and it will resolve.